# Iphone app development from monodevelop

Tags: iphone, ubuntu, mono, monodevelop

Is it possible to develop iphone apps from monodevelop
how to do it from ubuntu

Comment: you can write iOS apps using MonoTouch and MonoDevelop, but it still requires a Mac.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry. Not yet, You need a Mac to write iPhone apps.

It is potentially possible with alot of work setting up the cross compilers ( apple release the gcc sources it uses about a year after doing xcode releases ).

I've built a few simple c demos but it was hours and hours of work to get a toolchain that works. Getting mono working on top would be more and more hours.

Answer (score 2):

You can run OS X in VirtualBox, although best to check licence terms.
See here http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-20005524-263.html

EDIT: to clarify, it must be Snow Leopard Server.

Comment: OS X license agreement forbids such virtualization usage as a whole, so any attempt like this is considered as evil. That's why you received so many down votes. You may delete this answer as soon as possible to avoid more loss in your credit.

Comment: Snow Leopard Server is permitted for use on a VM.

Comment: This answer basically is 'use OSX instead'  which isn't answering the question

Comment: The question is "how to do it from ubuntu". 1) Purchase a copy of Snow Leopard Server. 2) install on VirtualBox (free). If you cant afford a Mac, then it's a viable solution.